# Is P the set of all algorithms whose run-time is $O\left( n^{ O \left( 1 \right) }\right)$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

I'm coming to Computer Science from Mathematics and am familiar with the idea of building classes of objects using Propositional Logic. Namely, start with some universe of objects, define some proposition $P \left( x \right)$, and then iterate over the universe of objects, applying $P \left( x \right)$ to each; keep the objects for which $P \left( x \right)$ is true; exclude each object for which $P \left( x \right)$ is false.

So, when we define a class of objects called $\mathbb{P}$ ([as in P vs NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)), I really need to see a formal definition of the proposition used to build that class--as well as a formal definition of the universe of objects we're starting with.

#### Defining the Universe of Discourse, $\mathbb{U}$

My understanding is that, for the question of $\mathbb{P}$ vs $\mathbb{NP}$, our universe of discourse is all [decision problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) that are [satisfiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability). Namely, problems that can be implemented in boolean logic, return a boolean result, and that someone somewhere at some point has found a finite sequence of inputs that cause the implementation to return $TRUE$.

In spite of Russell's Paradox, let us define our universe of discourse as the set $\mathbb{U}$.

#### Defining $\mathbb{P}$

$\mathbb{P}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{U}$. Namely, it is the set of all objects in $\mathbb{U}$ for which the following proposition returns $TRUE$:

> This object can be written as a decision problem that returns a boolean value--and that decision problem takes at most $O \left( n^{O \left( 1 \right)} \right)$ time.

That is, given some implementation of a decision problem in $\mathbb{U}$, if that implementation takes at most polynomial time, we can include that implementation in $\mathbb{P}$.

#### The Point I Need Clarified

Are we really using $O \left( n^{O \left( 1 \right)} \right)$ to define $\mathbb{P}$? Or are we using $\theta \left( n^{O \left( 1 \right)} \right)$? $O \left( n^{O \left( 1 \right)} \right)$ seems right to me, but--so often material I study from doesn't distinguish between Big-O and Big-Theta. So, I need to clarify.

For example, given the following simple, Java-like implementation of an algorithm:

```
function boolean isOne(int input) {
    return input == 1;
}
```

Should I include this algorithm in $\mathbb{P}$? It is clearly faster than polynomial time; it is constant time. So, it is $O \left( n^{O \left( 1 \right)} \right)$ but not $\theta \left( n^{O \left( 1 \right)} \right)$--as long as zero $\not\in O \left( 1 \right)$?

Should I include it in $\mathbb{P}$?

If zero $\in O \left( 1 \right)$, then is a constant time algorithm in $\theta \left( n^{O \left( 1 \right)} \right)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I include this algorithm in $\mathbb{P}$?

Yes. Since the algorithm is asymptotically bounded above by $O(n)$ the algorithm is in $\mathbb{P}$.

> If zero $\in O(1)$, . . .

Zero is in $O(1)$.

> . . . so often material I study from doesn't distinguish between Big-O and Big-Theta

big-O pertains to an asymptotic upper bound, where big-Theta pertains to an asymptotic tight bound.

The formal definition: $$f(n) \in O(g(n)) \iff \exists N_0,c\in\mathbb{R}^+ \text{ such that } n>N_0 \implies 0 \leq f(n) \leq cg(n)$$ Also, $$f(n) \in \Theta(g(n)) \iff \exists N_0, c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}^+ \text{ such that } n>N_0 \implies c_1g(n)\leq f(n)\leq c_2g(n)$$

For example, $f(n) = n^2 + 3n \in O(n^3)$ and $f(n) \in O(n^2)$. But, $f(n) \not\in \Theta(n^3)$, yet $f(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$.

We can't use $\Theta(n^{O(1)})$ to describe $\mathbb{P}$, as $O(lg(n))$ isn't in $\Theta(n^{O(1)})$, but is in $O(n^{O(1)})$ (and is in $\mathbb{P}$).

Comment: I find some things in this answer confusing. An algorithm can not be in P, and neither can $O(lg(n))$ be in P. These are not the right types of objects.

Answer (score 0):

P is not a set of algorithms, it is a set of *languages*, where a language is a subset of $\{0, 1\}^*$. In your terminology, the universe of discourse is the power set of $\{0, 1\}^*$ (Russell's paradox is not an issue). P contains exactly those languages $L$ for which there exists a Turing machine $M$ with the following properties.

- When given any $x \in \{0, 1\}^*$ as input, $M$ returns *yes* if $x \in L$, otherwise it returns *no*.
- The time complexity function $f_M(n)$ of $M$ is $O(p(n))$ for some polynomial $p$. The time complexity function $f_M(n)$ gives the maximum number of steps for $M$ to halt (with answer *yes* or *no*) on any input $x \in \{0, 1\}^*$ such that $n = |x|$.